# Dictionary initialization syntax

Tags: python, dictionary, initialization

```
def __init__(self, devices, queue):
    '''
    '''
    self.devices = devices
    self.queue = queue

    values = {k:0 for k in devices.keys()}
    values[0xbeef] = len(values) # the number of devices
    super(CallbackDataBlock, self).__init__(values)
```

Can someone help me explain the following two lines:

1. `values = {k:0 for k in devices.keys()}`
   What does `k:0` do?
2. `values[0xbeef] = len(values) # the number of devices`
   Does this mean that new item `{0xbeef: length}` is appended in the `dict`?

Comment: You should use a debugger or print statements to examine the contents of `values` after each of those lines, then you wouldn't need to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `k` is the field in the dictionary. The set of all fields is stored in the `device.keys()` which is most probably a list, we loop through the list, take names of fields and initialize them by zero.
2. Yes, you are right. The next statement is responsible for adding a new field and initializing it to the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`{k:0 for k in devices.keys()}` creates a dictionary with all keys and 0 for all values. And your assessment is correct, it creates a new key with `{value of 0xbeef : number of keys in the dictionary}`

Answer (score 0):

in python documentation you can see [List Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)

### this pattern is important :

```
expression  for  item  in  list  if  conditional else
```

or for simple usage :

```
expression  for  item  in  list
```

#### in list data type we can use :

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
a = [x for x in list]
print (a)
```

printed :

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and we have :

```
a = [x*2 for x in list]
print (a)
```

printed :

```
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

#### and for dictionary

in dictionary we have this syntax:

```
{key1:value1, key2:value2, . . .}
```

and example :

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
d = [k:0 for k in list]
print (d)
```

in example `k:0` maens : put `0` for value of each k

printed :

```
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

### one more thing :

python dictionary have to Helpful method:`dict.keys()`,`dict.values()`
when we use `dict.keys`, python return a list of dict's keys

```
d = {"name":"sam", "job":"programer", "salary":"25000"}
print(d.keys())
print(d.values())
```

printed :

```
['name','job','salary']
['sam','programer','25000']
```

for add a new object in a dictionary we use :

```
d[newkey]= newValue
```

for example :

```
d[10] = 'mary'
print(d[10])
```

printed :

```
'mary'
```

## now your answer :

in your code

1) `k:0` maens : put `0` for value of each k 
2) 0xbeef is a `hex` code == 48879 in decimal

```
    values[48879] = len(values)
```

its fill by length of list.